# java regex month 2 digits

Tags: java, regex

I want to catch only one of the following:

```
01 , 02 , ... , 09 , 10 , 11 , 12
```

Is the following regex is complete or I missed something?

```
String monthPat = "^[1][0-2]|[0][1-9]$"
```

Comment: Write a unit test and feed it those strings and a few illegal ones, like 13 and 23...

Comment: @Rob I think `10` is a valid month.

Comment: Please check it yourself, then you can ask for improvements

Comment: It catches all the above but I am afraid it can catch other things. I am not sure if I used [] and | correctly

Comment: @user1692261 So try giving it other things.

Comment: @user1692261 That's what *testing* is for...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue with your current regex is that with the alternation, you are trying to match one of the following expressions:

```
^[1][0-2]     # strings that start with '10', '11', or '12'
[0][1-9]$     # strings that end with '01' through '09'
```

This means that you can have partial matches of longer strings, for example you will match the "10" at the beginning of "1000", and the "09" at the end of "2009".

Make sure you include both anchors on each side of the `|` to fix this:

```
^1[0-2]$|^0[1-9]$
```

Alternatively, you can do the alternation inside of a group and put the anchors on the outside:

```
^(1[0-2]|0[1-9])$
```

Note that I also removed the character class (square brackets) from `[1]` and `[0]`, since the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you are doing validation. If you are doing them with `matches` method in String class, then the anchors `^` and `$` are unnecessary.

You can make it a bit shorter, as the character class are not needed when there is only 1 character:

```
"1[0-2]|0[1-9]"
```

The improved regex above can be used if you use it with `matches` method in String class, since `matches` method will return `true` if the pattern provided matches the whole string.

Note that your regex have slightly different meaning if it is considered alone.

```
"^[1][0-2]|[0][1-9]$"
```

If you feed this to `Pattern.compile`, then use `Matcher.find` class, this will match substring that starts with 10 to 12, or ends with 01 to 09, since the alternation will alternate between 2 subpatterns: `^[1][0-2]` and `[0][1-9]$`. Change it to

```
"^(?:1[0-2]|0[1-9])$"
```

and it will only find match if the string is exactly 01 to 12.

This knowledge is useful when you write code in other languages, since `match` method of String class/utility that works with regex may return substring that matches the regex if you don't specify the anchors `^` and `$`.